# Why my boxplot does not show a clear boxes in plot?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, boxplot

I am trying to boxplot using seaborn in python but it does not show any clear boxes in my plot.
Here is my plotted figure:

[image: my figure]

it just showing me tiny rectangle sahpes.But I am expecting to have a clear boxes in my plot like this figure

[image: example figure]

here is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import seaborn as sns
df = pd.read_csv(path)
sns.boxplot(data=df, x='ch_name', y='E_theta',hue='ch_name')
```

Here is the example of my dataset

```
ch_name E_theta
Fp1 3.7759641788051466e-09
F7  3.0204119808710332e-09
F3  2.091325331947269e-09
FC1 1.669620474356091e-09
FC2 3.161196872185518e-09
F4  5.114842906974197e-09
F8  1.353881066129044e-10
Fp2 6.714466796058576e-09
```

Comment: Could you provide the sample data you used in your code!

Comment: Not clear on what you want. However, box plots are used to give descriptive stats of a dataset. Either there is not big variance in your data and hence there are no whiskers meaning there are no outliers, or the values are too close that the interquatile range is negligible. This would then mean the box is flattened. You could also be plotting to many variables and hence very small plots resulting.

Comment: @Snehil,I updated my code with the example of my dataset.

Comment: @wwnde,I want to see a clear visible boxes in my plot.

Comment: @ Fatema Sultana you  are getting the correct boxplot for the data you are feeding. Boxplots are used to see statistical properties of  variables for given  dataset,In your datasets every point is repeating only once , so you are getting a boxplot which is similar to a point plot or say a scatterplot coz it have  absolute values.If you want a boxplot with big boxes like this https://imgur.com/a/nojhgJw , you have to include more data for each category of ch_name

Comment: @Snehil,thank you ! Now it is clear to me.